# WHILE condition with sub IF statements in SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got the following code in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
..
@currentAccID     char(21), 
@currentUserID    char(21),
@UserID1    char(21),
@UserID2    char(21),
@UserID3    char(21),
@Case     smallint, 

...
SELECT @UserID1 = UserID1, @UserID2 = UserID2, @UserID3 = UserID3 FROM OLD_Users WHERE oldAccID = @currentAccID

WHILE (@userid1 = @userid or @userid2 = @userid or @userid3 = @userid)
BEGIN
    IF (@Case = 10 OR @Case = 20) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_NormalUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 12 OR @Case = 22)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_MediumUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 13 OR @Case = 23)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_HighUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 14 OR @Case = 24)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_UltraUser'
    END
END

WHILE (@userid1 != @userid or @userid2 != @userid or @userid3 != @userid)
BEGIN
    IF (@Case = 10 OR @Case = 20) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'NormalUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 12 OR @Case = 22)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'MediumUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 13 OR @Case = 23)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'HighUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 14 OR @Case = 24)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'UltraUser'
    END
END

...
INSERT INTO NewUser (UserID,Case,Equipment ......) VALUES (@UserID,@Case,@Equipment .......)
```

Is the above code correct? Also, there is a third possibility where `@currentAccID` doesn't match at all with `oldAccID` from `OLD_Users` table with the `SELECT` query but still it should be fine because the second `WHILE` statement will be executed, right? and there shouldn't be a problem with the performance? I am pretty sure this can be done a lot better with the `WHILE` statements and etc but I am not good at SQL stored procedures. Thank you in advance for spending time to help me out!

Comment: You are using `while` here and not updating the parameters used in the the `while-condition`. If the control moves in any of these `while`, it will never come out of it. Please specify your need. What you want to achieve with this code.

Comment: @thisisbobbs - I want to achieve the following: If there is a match for `@AccID` and `@UserID` in the first `WHILE` statement then execute the code `if` blocks inside it and then move to the `INSERT` query below. However, If there is no match for `@AccID` and `UserID` then execute the code `if` block statements from the second `WHILE` and then move to the `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should not use `while` loops. It can be achieved by simple `if-else` statements. Please use the following code to do the same:

```
..
@currentAccID     char(21), 
@currentUserID    char(21),
@UserID1    char(21),
@UserID2    char(21),
@UserID3    char(21),
@Case     smallint, 

...
-- this condition checks whether @userid is present in any of the columns UseID1 or UserID2 or UserID3
IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM OLD_Users WHERE oldAccID = @currentAccID AND (UserID1 = @userid OR UserID2 = @userid OR UserID3 = @userid))
BEGIN
    SET  @OldORNew = 1
    IF (@Case = 10 OR @Case = 20) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_NormalUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 12 OR @Case = 22)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_MediumUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 13 OR @Case = 23)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_HighUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 14 OR @Case = 24)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'OLD_UltraUser'
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET  @OldORNew = 0
    IF (@Case = 10 OR @Case = 20) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'NormalUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 12 OR @Case = 22)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'MediumUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 13 OR @Case = 23)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'HighUser'
    END
    ELSE IF (@Case = 14 OR @Case = 24)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Equipment = Equipment FROM Users WHERE UserID = 'UltraUser'
    END
END

...
INSERT INTO NewUser (UserID,Case,Equipment ......) VALUES (@UserID,@Case,@Equipment .......)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you a lot. I hope you have a great day! Before I accept the answer, please let me know as I am curious, why we select `NULL` instead just to select the three columns: `UserID1`, `UserID2`, `UserID3` ?

Comment: We are omitting them as we are not going to utilize them anywhere. We are just checking whether the row exists or not. In this scenario, it does not matter what columns you are selecting. `EXISTS` only checks whether any row was fetched or not. It does not focus on what was selected.

Comment: You can select any columns if you want. It will not affect the functionality of your stored procedure. But if the statement is not utilizing it, then there is no need to select them. I'd advise not to select any column in `EXISTS` statements.

Comment: I thought that we should select `UserID1, UserID2, UserID3` to make sure the comparison `(UserID1 = @userid OR UserID2 = @userid OR UserID3 = @userid)` is done properly because these three columns are from the same table - `OLD_Users`. Or it's fine the way it is? Shouldn't the statement utilize them for the comparison?

Comment: This comparison is done in the `where` clause. You need not to write the same comparison again.

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot! You seems a really nice person. I will be in need of similar SQL stuff from time to time. If you have free time, please feel free to send me your contact details. I will pay for a specific job done when I need them. Thank you again!

Comment: @Plar625 Sure! You can contact me here: swamibabulal@gmail.com

Comment: Cool. Thank you again. However, I am really sorry to bother you but I forgot something really important to add on this code above. I will need to include a new column `OldORNew` in the `INSERT` query which will have values `0` or `1`. Basically if there is a match for the first case aka `@accid` and `@userid` is present in `IF EXISTS` check then set the value of `@OldORNew` to be `1` else if the second code block is executed then the value of `@OldORNew` should be set `0`. I that way I will include it into the `INSERT` query to distinguish wish case was used if old or new user. THANKS A LOT!